# login failed for user: The user is not associated with a trusted sql server connection?

Tags: sql-server-2005

We have an access front-end tied to a sql server 2005 back end. We have no trouble with any users accessing the interfaces with the exception of one. 
When trying to interact with the interfaces we get a SQL Server Connection Error telling us that the user is not associated with the trusted sql server connection. 
We are use mixed mode authentication so that is not the problem. We also thought it may be the computer itself, but the user gets the same error on multiple computers. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried logging into SQL Server directly using the same credentials?

Comment: Is the user of the same domain as the machine or different?

Comment: The domain acount is on a different domain than the server, and no trust is set up. However other domain accounts have no problem accessing the server.

Comment: What is also strange is that when the error show the username name that we are trying is not shown in the acutal error! e.g. 
login failed for user ' '. 
instead of 
login failed for user 'margaretf'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpected characters in the username?

Answer (score 1):

Where we see it the user password has changed after login.

Fix: log out and back in. Or lock the PC and unlock.

This way, you re-auth against AD and the NT login token is refreshed/renewed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the actual account that is connecting? I've found on several occasions the authenticating account is a service account or something other than I intended. Include the intended domain to be sure. I've been caught by local admin vs domain admin as well.

Also fire up the SQL profiler and see what transactions are actually taking place.